# Access specific file in Flash with fileReference

Tags: flash, filereference

I need to make a flash applet that automatically grabs a specific file on a user's system (iTunes XML file) and auto uploads it to my server. So far I have only been able to accomplish this with a user selecting the file, but I was wondering if anybody knew how to upload a specific file without the user having to go and find it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible when considering the security implications.